# Centering raster from randomly created points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, convert, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1. I have species data (point file) that I have used to extract raster values from. Each point represents an observation given by an 8 fig. grid ref so I converted the points into a raster using the "point to raster" tool which created a raster with a 100m cell size. The centroid of each cell is perfectly aligned with the point file- excellent.

PROBLEM - I now need to create a "background" sample for a Maxent model using randomly generated points. I have used the "create random points" tool, constrained the extent to that of the shapefile for my area (the UK) and generated my random points. When I then use the "point to raster" tool the cells of the raster produced are not aligned uniformly with the original point file. The projected coordinate system and geographic coordinate system of the random points is the same as that of the genuine points so why is the raster not aligning as before? Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: sorry, ArcMap 10.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [snap raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm) environment setting when you run the point to raster tool. This will ensure the output raster is aligned to the raster you specify in the environment setting.

Comment: The output raster needs to be aligned with the center of the points not another raster though so is that likely to apply?